# Creating a new column by a condition and selecting the maximum value by shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [10, 20, 30, 400, 50, 60],
        'b': [897, 9, 33, 4, 55, 65]
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `c`.

```
     a    b      c
0   10  897    NaN
1   20    9  897.0
2   30   33    NaN
3  400    4  400.0
4   50   55    NaN
5   60   65    NaN
```

These are the steps needed:

a) Find rows that `df.a > df.b`

b) From the above rows compare the value from `a` to its previous value from `b`. If it was more than previous `b` value, put `a` in column `c` otherwise put the previous `b`.

For example:

a) Rows `1` and `3` met `df.a > df.b`

b) From row `1`, 20 is less than 897 so 897 is chosen. However in row `3`, 400 is greater than 33 so it is selected.

This image clarifies the point:

[image]

This is what I have tried but it does not work:

```
df.loc[df.a > df.b, 'c'] = max(df.a, df.b.shift(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = df.a > df.b
df.loc[mask, "c"] = np.where(df["a"] > df["b"].shift(), df["a"], df["b"].shift())[mask]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     a    b      c
0   10  897    NaN
1   20    9  897.0
2   30   33    NaN
3  400    4  400.0
4   50   55    NaN
5   60   65    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum with the appropriate shift using `np.maximum` and `Series.shift()`, and then you can fill in the remaining rows with NaNs by using `np.where()`:

```
df["c"] = np.where(
    df["a"] > df["b"],                     # If value in "a" > value in "b"
    np.maximum(df["a"], df["b"].shift(1)), # Use the max of "a" and shifted "b"
    np.nan                                 # Otherwise, fill with NaN
)
df
```

This outputs:

```
     a    b      c
0   10  897    NaN
1   20    9  897.0
2   30   33    NaN
3  400    4  400.0
4   50   55    NaN
5   60   65    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

use mask & rolling

```
cond = df['a'] > df['b']
df.loc[cond, 'c'] = df['b'].mask(cond, df['a']).rolling(2).max()
```

df

```
     a    b      c
0   10  897    NaN
1   20    9  897.0
2   30   33    NaN
3  400    4  400.0
4   50   55    NaN
5   60   65    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['b'].shift().gt(df['a']), df['b'].shift(), df['a'])
df['c'] = df['c'].where(df['a'].gt(df['b']))
```

Output:

```
     a    b      c
0   10  897    NaN
1   20    9  897.0
2   30   33    NaN
3  400    4  400.0
4   50   55    NaN
5   60   65    NaN
```